# Does Mono now support Entity Framework CodeFirst?

Tags: mono, entity-framework-4.1

Title says it; their compatibility page says "Entity Framework", but I know codefirst is a separate install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Mono forked the [open source Entity Framework project](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) which includes Code First, Migrations, Enums, etc.

Comment: hm... any idea which fork it is?

Comment: thanks, I found it after posting that question. Haven't been able to get MonoDevelop to open it yet, though, it treats the .sln file as if it were raw binary (ie opens hex editor).

Comment: Sorry, Brice, I've visited your blog several times, and even used a tutorial to help me get MVC4 up and running. I'm now trying to port a rather large project to MonoDevelop atm, and I can get everything working but the Linq to Entities code. Mono Uses the EF and recognizes it but when ran, I get a typeloader exception

Comment: @Chazt3n Our team (EF) doesn't officially support Mono yet. I'd recommend filing a bug against the Mono team's EF branch. We will, of course, consider any pull requests they send our way.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I'm going to give Nhibernate a shot, but having used EF since it's inception I'll be a little hurt. Have you ever seen an example of EF working at all in mono? and if so do you know someone I could talk to about getting it up and running? I would love to contribute at some point as well, although my main concern is getting my company OpenSource (40k licensing a year is starting to cut a little deep) And switching frameworks on a CRM will take a whiiile I'm assuming.

Comment: @Chazt3n: Did you find any examples? I was trying to setup a test project with Mono + EF, but didn't get very far (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624065/how-to-setup-entity-framework-sql-server-with-mono).

Comment: I can't see it working, I did however get NHibernate up and running with mysql on ubuntu